# Sometimes service get called and sometime it doesn't

Tags: android, service

I have an activity which stores some data (edittext and image) in database.
Service runs sometime and sometime it doesn't . I am taking the image for imageview plus some text data and passing it to the service which calls my database class. Why isn't the service getting called every time ??

passing data to service :

```
 imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    if(imgView.getDrawable()==null) {
        imageData = null ;
    }
    else {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imgView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            imageData = getBytes(bitmap);
    }

    Intent i = new Intent(this,TaskService.class);
    i.putExtra("heading",s);
    i.putExtra("subject",s1);
    i.putExtra("date",s2);
    i.putExtra("notes",s3);
    i.putExtra("imageData",imageData);
    startService(i);
```

and this is my service class :(TaskDatabaseClass this is my db class)

```
public class TaskService extends Service {

String s,s1,s2,s3;
byte[] imagedata;
public TaskService() {
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    s = intent.getStringExtra("heading");
    s1 = intent.getStringExtra("subject");
    s2 = intent.getStringExtra("date");
    s3 = intent.getStringExtra("notes");
    imagedata = intent.getByteArrayExtra("imageData");

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                TaskDatabaseClass enterData = new  TaskDatabaseClass(TaskService.this);
                enterData.open();
                enterData.createEntry(s,s1,s2,s3,imagedata);
                enterData.close();
            }catch(Exception e) {
                }
        }
    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(r);
    thread.start();
    this.stopSelf();
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i(TAG ," destroying ");
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
   // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    return null;
```

Comment: I think it is because you are stopping the service- As per doccumentations only single call to stop self stopes the whole service

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html can you try with stopself(startId);

Comment: @X3Btel he's returning `START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY`. So, a `stopSelf()` should be enough.

Comment: Why are you calling `stopSelf()` right after starting a new thread?

Comment: I don't want my service to run on background , it should execute its part and then rest until the next time it is called .@X3Btel @Shaishav

Comment: i have tried to check by inserting Logs , my service doesn't enter its onStartCommand @Shaishav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are doing a bit of database write operation in your `Service`. This seems redundant as Android services aren't suitable for these tasks (not that they would be useless). If you simply need to spawn a new thread then, you can call the same operation in a new thread (just like in your service) from even your `Activity` and it would be much efficient that current setup.

Doing this task in the `Service` not only creates a overhead on the Android system of creating a `Service` and maintaining its life-cycle, even you need to worry about data transfer via intents which is an additional overhead on the system.

You can read more about the uses of `Services` over [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) under the heading "What is Service".

Comment: I will do as you said and then inform you !!

Comment: some problems are reduced . Thanks!